# Rewriting $\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$ into $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/h^2}+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(Sorry for two posts in a row) I'm not sure how to rearrange $$\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$ got from the previous ask into $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/h^2}+1}$$

I did $$\frac{h^2-h^2+h}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$ and am thinking of having $$\frac{h}{h\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$ which would cancel out the $h$ factor in the denominator and give me 1 on the numerator, but I'm having difficulty actually making $\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h$ agree with the $h$ factor. Is this the right way to go about it? Thanks for helping.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken $$\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+h}+h} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 1/h} + 1}$$ How can they be equal?

Comment: That bugged me as well. I thought I did some wrong calculations, now I'm wondering if there was a mistake to the textbook's author's part.

Comment: And by the way VIVID's derivation only works for $h>0$. Since for $h<0$,  $h=-\sqrt{h^2}$.